# Firebase hosting custom domain shows "Site Not Found

Tags: firebase, dns, hosting

I was having a static file hosting in a firebase project. I deleted the project by mistake and lost my domain A record and TXT records.

I recreated a new firebase hosting project and deployed my static website again. It works fine for default firebase hosting https://jawsandteeth-website.firebaseapp.com/

HOwever, when I connect my custom domain again with A record and TXT record, the project hosting dashboard is showing custom domain is in connected state. however the URL [www.jawsandteeth.com](http://www.jawsandteeth.com) shows "Site Not Found" error. It has been 2 days and not sure if waiting more time is going to help.

Could someone help on this regards? Any leads is much appreciated.

Expecting custom domain to show same content as default firebase hosting

Comment: Below is my firebase config

{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}

and static files are in public folder

Comment: My git repo
https://github.com/jawsandteeth/website